# php explode not working in javascript template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, template-engine

I'm aware of some posts already dealing with the same topic.

Following are the links:

[Javascript Template Engine Use with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520241/javascript-template-engine-use-with-jquery)

[What is x-tmpl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl)

I'm trying to incorporate a php explode function into a javascript template. The plugin is  jQuery-File-Upload from blueimp @ https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/downloads i downloaded off GitHub.

Following is part of my code i'm trying to execute and make it work.

```
         <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
         <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
         {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
             <tr>
                <td>
                     <?php echo "{%=file.name%}"; ?> //{%file.name%} contains a string seperated by underscores
                     <?php $file_name_long = '{%=file.name%}'; ?>
                     <?php $file_name = explode ('_' , $file_name_long); ?>
                     <?php print_r($file_name); ?>
                </td>
             </tr>
               ...
               ...
```

I'm able to make $file_name print out as an array but I'm not able to get it seperated by the underscore within my **file.name**. the printed array contains the whole string as per **file.name**.

I'm not sure if this is even possible. I've been trying all day. If this is not do-able or logically incorrect, do let me know so that i can stop trying to want to make this work. Thanks and appreciated.

Comment: Would you  please provide the currently generated output?

Comment: I'm getting this-->  vendor_unknown_Pearls.gif Array ( [0] => vendor_unknown_Pearls.gif )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your are trying to read javascript values in your php code.

`{%=file.name%}` is simply a string to php and contains no actual filenames when your php renders the output. so your print_r() would output `{%=file.name%}` which then gets translated into your filename later in the browser after the whole php processing is done.

try implementing this stuff in javascript alone.

Comment: meaning doing the explode in javascript?

Comment: yes. but you have to figure out how to run javascript inside your template files. javascript equivalent of explode() is `split()`

Comment: hmm. but i wouldn't be able to add the split directly yah? coz its a template script..? Will it show some error?

Comment: nice. Done. Did a split() function within the template. Then set up condition to restrict the type of photos to show. Thanks Jan. Should have asked sooner. Would have saved me soo much time.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute server-side code (php) on the client (in your js template). The code `{%=file.name%}` hasn't been replaced at the time that your php code is trying to execute it (because that's on the server).

If you mix server-side and client-side code, you really need to manage your logic to account for the server executing before the client.

Comment: I think i get it to some extend. meaning when it goes into explode function, {%=file.name%} doesn't get converted into the actual filename but just remain as the current form. That is why the values of the filename doesn't get exploded to the form i want.